# ssh-copy-id versus manual copy id_rsa.pub

Tags: ssh, command-line, ssh-config

From one day to another, our company server started to ask me for my SSH password.

First thing that I checked was to see if my key was inside `.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server. My key was inside, nothing changed. Also in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` nothing has changed.

Then I tried to do [this procedure](https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/) on freshly installed Ubuntu16 server. After completing these 5 steps, new server asked me again for SSH password.

The `ssh-copy-id` command has finally accomplished keyless SSH login, but I have noticed that that `.ssh/authorized_keys` has three lines: one starting with `ssh-dss` and 2x starting with `ssh-rsa`

Now I remember that 5 steps procedure from the link above has worked in the past with only one key.

Has something changed recently? Why procedure from above does not work anymore?

Edit:
Since `ssh-copy-id` copies altogether 3 keys to `.ssh/authorized_keys` those keys can be found in following files:

`~/.ssh/id_dsa`

`~/.ssh/sshkey.pub`

`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

so I deleted line by line from remote's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file

deleted `~/.ssh/id_dsa` line - auto login succeeded

deleted `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` line - auto login succeeded

deleted `~/.ssh/sshkey.pub` line - auto login **not** succeeded - asked for password

Only content from `~/.ssh/sshkey.pub` is necessary.
Why SSH is comparing `sshkey.pub` and not `id_rsa.pub` like in the example from online tutorial?

Comment: Certainly not because of any fundamental changes to authorized_keys file or I would have woken up one day to find myself locked out of a whole bunch of machines.

Comment: what kind of key, and how many bits?  the server you're having problems with may have higher standards, possibly due to an upgrade of sshd.  1024 bit RSA used to be considered acceptable.  nowadays 2048 or 4096 bit are required.

Comment: also, please add the output of `ssh -v your-remote-server` to your question.

Comment: Do you still have the 640 flags on authorized_keys or something more restrictive (600)?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that `ssh-copy-id` is merely a convenience function. It checks whether the keys were already exported to the machine, it creates `.ssh` directory if necessary, but basically it just adds public keys to `.ssh/authorized_keys`. `ssh-copy-id` is a shell script (in openssh), so you can read its code (`` vi `which ssh-copy-id` `` ) in the end:

```
[ "$DRY_RUN" ] || printf '%s\n' "$NEW_IDS" | \
  ssh "$@" "exec sh -c 'cd ; umask 077 ; mkdir -p .ssh && { [ -z "'`tail -1c .ssh/authorized_keys 2>/dev/null`'" ] || echo >> .ssh/authorized_keys ; } && cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys || exit 1 ; if type restorecon >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then restorecon -F .ssh .ssh/authorized_keys ; fi'" \
  || exit 1
```

During authentication only `authorized_keys` are checked. From openssh [documentation](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#AUTHENTICATION):

> The file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys lists the public keys that are permitted for logging in. When the user logs in, the ssh program tells the server which key pair it would like to use for authentication. The client proves that it has access to the private key and the server checks that the corresponding public key is authorized to accept the account.

I hope this answers your question title "ssh-copy-id versus manual copy id_rsa.pub". This file `~/.ssh/sshkey.pub` I don't have, so I hope you solved the problems with your setup yourself. Anyway, yes, you can just manually copy the public key to `authorized_keys` not using `ssh-copy-id`.

UPD: in 2020 (OpenSSH 8.2) [RSA SHA-1 keys became deprecated](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html). Alternatives should be used (see the link).

Comment: Note that the actual RSA algorithm is not getting deprecated, just the use of SHA1 hash function that was originally specified to be used with it. With older versions of OpenSSH, `ssh-keygen -t rsa` would have created a `rsa-sha1` key, which is now being deprecated. New versions will instead generate `rsa-sha2-512` keys by default. By specifying `-t rsa-sha2-256` you can get a reduced-length version if necessary for performance, or with `-t rsa-sha1` you can get a classic RSA key that is now being deprecated, if you absolutely need one. The default name for the key will still be `id_rsa[.pub]`

Comment: @telcoM thank you, I fixed my update! That was written wrongly in the link I found. In the current formulation this update may make little sense. However, I decided to leave that here, because I faced this problem with RSA keys on exactly one machine (connecting to exactly one server). I solved this problem by updating `autossh` on the server.